# How to check for entity type in Views when using hook_field_access?

Tags: views, entities, users

I have some code that checks user access to a certain field using hook_field_access below.

The code runs fine when viewing nodes normally, but throws an error when viewing a node of type 'lesson' through a View:

*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object*

The error comes from the check for entity type: $entity->type == 'lesson'

If I debug with:

```
dpm($entity->type);
```

I get the right value ('lesson'), so the check seems to work.

How can I resolve this error?

```
function HOOK_utility_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {

  //Check video field only when attached to 'lesson'.
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_video' && $entity_type == 'node' && $op == 'view' && $entity->type == 'lesson') {

    //Grant access only if user is logged in.
    if ($account->uid > 0) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not running twice, once when `$entity` is populated and once it isn't?

Comment: @Clive - I think that's it. If I move dpm($entity); to the top, it's actually invoked 5 times, and the first time the entity is empty. Should I just add If ($entity); somewhere?

Comment: `is_object()` might be better but yeah, that would do it. Sometimes these hooks get called for new entities, and `$entity` isn't available yet. Or there may be a dodgy field in your install somewhere which is lacking an entity when it should have one in this context. If you're not up for a serious debug sesh then yeah, bandage it up :)

Comment: Adding if (is_object($entity)) worked, thanks. Housekeeping: is it recommended to add this as an answer and then accept, in order to close out the question?

Comment: I'd go so far as to say it's _encouraged_ :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @clive's comment above, I adjusted the code to check that $entity is actually present. I'm not sure if this is a problem unique to my install or not. I only saw the error when viewing a node of type 'lesson' through a paged view that depends on some custom relationship code, so entirely possible the error is mine somewhere in a custom module.

```
function HOOK_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {

      //Check to make sure we have an entity. Abort if not.
      if (is_object($entity)) {

        //Check video field only when attached to 'lesson'.
        if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_video' && $entity_type == 'node' && $op == 'view' && $entity->type == 'lesson') {

          //Grant access only if user is logged in.
          if ($account->uid > 0) {
            return TRUE;
          }
          return FALSE;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your conditional statement won't work as it is.  You are checking for $entity_type to be 'node' and $entity->type to be 'lesson' and I feel that's a bit conflicted.

Also, if I understand the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) correctly, `$entity` is optional, so it's probably better to check $entity_type:

`if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_video' && $entity_type == 'lesson' && $op == 'view')`

or maybe check that $entity is an object before you check the value.

Comment: `$entity` is definitely not optional. But there's nothing to stop a caller passing it as `NULL` or whatever. Also the `$entity_type` is the _type of entity_ (node, user, taxonomy_term, etc). `$entity->type` in this context is equivalent to `$node->type`, which is querying the _bundle_ of the node (its type). They're not the same thing so you can use one to check for the other

Comment: I stand corrected, I was ignoring the scope. However the API lists $entity as "(optional)", but it probably means "possibly NULL".

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that actually - seems like the params themselves should be optional in code if that's true. I guess either the docs or the code could be wrong, but one of them is